# QFT: Ground State Momentum - Normalisation of States

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, operators, hilbert-space

In my notes I have,

$$
\left\langle \mathbf{p} \left| \mathbf{q} \right.\right\rangle
=
\left\langle 0 \left| 
{a(\mathbf{p})}\ 
{a(\mathbf{q})}^{\dagger}
\right| 0 \right\rangle
$$
I am not sure how the step is then made to obtain the commutator as below,
$$=
\left\langle 0\left| 
\left[{a(\mathbf{p})},
{a(\mathbf{q})}^{\dagger}\right]
\right|0\right\rangle
=
(2\pi)^3
2E_{\mathbf{p}}
\delta^3(\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{q})
$$

Comment: If the state $\left|0\right\rangle$ is the normalized Fock vacuum state defined by absence of any particles ie $a(p)\left|0\right\rangle=0$ $\forall p$, then 
$\left\langle 0 \left| 
{a(p)}\ 
{a(q)}^{\dagger}
\right| 0 \right\rangle = \left\langle 0 \left| 
[{a(p)},\ 
{a(q)}^{\dagger}]
\right| 0 \right\rangle$. The RHS gives the commutator. $(2\pi)^3E_p$ in the commutator is a normalization choice (See [Srednicki](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf) Chapter-3).

Comment: Thanks, so basically add zero, as 

$$
{a(\mathbf{p})}
{a(\mathbf{q})}^{\dagger}
= 
{a(\mathbf{p})}
{a(\mathbf{q})}^{\dagger}
-
{a(\mathbf{q})}^{\dagger}
{a(\mathbf{p})}
+ 
{a(\mathbf{q})}^{\dagger}
{a(\mathbf{p})}
=
\left[
    {a(\mathbf{p})},{a(\mathbf{q})}^{\dagger}
\right]
+
{a(\mathbf{q})}^{\dagger}
{a(\mathbf{p})}
$$

where ${a(\mathbf{q})}^{\dagger}{a(\mathbf{p})}$ vanished in the VEV. Thanks!